# Determine if the series converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Question: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cfrac{\ (n+1)!(n+2)!}{n^{2n}}$$

I have identified the ratio test and have reached this stage but I'm not sure what to do from here.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\cfrac{\ (n+2)(n+3)n^{2n}}{(n+1)^{2(n+1)}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite it as
$$
\frac{(n+2)(n+3)}{(n+1)^2}\left (\frac{1}{(1+1/n)^n}\right )^2
$$
which converges to $1/e^2 < 1$

Comment: Okay, sweet. How did you go from (n+1)^(n) to (1+(1/n))^n?  
  
Did it become n^(n) * (1+(1/n))^n and the n^(n) cancelled with the numerator?

Comment: and what was the next steps from what you did? How did you end up with e^(-2)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\frac{n^{2n}}{(n+1)^{2n}} = \left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^{-2}$$

**Edit:**
$$ \frac{(n+2)(n+3)}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{1+\frac5n+\frac6{n^2}}{1+\frac2n+\frac1{n^2}} \to 1$$

Comment: Thanks man, you have what the other guys has but the next step!  


I can see that it's a standard limit and that it's e^(-2) but what happens to the (n+2)(n+3)/(n+1)^2

Comment: $(n+2)(n+3)/(n+1)^2$ is $n^2$ and change divided by $n^2$ and change. Approaches $1$ as $n$ gets big.

Comment: @bof, hey mate, how is (n+2)(n+3)/(n+1)2 = n^2?  
  
I'm sorry if I don't get it, your reply sort of confused me. Feel free to submit a complete answer than commenting on someone elses, it helps me visualise it better too! Thanks!